# Is it possible to have a foreign key which isn't covering the whole primary key of the referenced table?

Tags: database, composite-primary-key

I have two tables:

Table A: with a composite primary key.

```
CommonID (PK) | Month (PK) | some data...
-----------------------------------------
1             | May 2011   | ...
1             | June 2011  | ...
2             | May 2011   | ...
2             | June 2011  | ...
```

Table B: referencing to table A

```
ID (PK) | A_CommonID (FK)| some data...
-----------------------------------------
...     | 1              | ...
...     | 2              | ...
```

As you can see table `B` isn't referencing the whole primary key but it will definitely always reference a unique entry in table `A` because there is a global value for the specified used month which will be used for `A.Month` in SQL-queries.

Now my question is, is that allowed or am I violating several rules of Database design?

I would really appreciate a nice answer because I will use it in the final document which I have to write for my bachelor's degree.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the sentence *but it will definitely always reference a unique entry in table A because...* Could you please clarify that part of your question?

Answer (score 1):

**No,** this is not allowed.

If you have a composite primary key consisting of more than one column, your foreign keys must also be **composite** and reference **all the columns** involved in your primary key.

A foreign key must reference the primary key, the whole key and nothing but the key (so help you Codd) :-)

What you might be able to do is to have a separate unique index on that `A_CommonID` column in `Table A` so that your `Table B` can reference that unique index (instead of the PK).